# collision detection only works correctly 2 sides with specific tile xna

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, collision-detection

This might be really simple but it is giving me a lot grief and I wondered if you guys would be able to shed some light on it. Basically I have a tile map which draws tiles at 64 * 64 and that works very well and they are drawn in a 2D array like this in the game1 class.

```
TileMap tileMap = new TileMap(new int[,]
    {
        { 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
        { 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 },
        { 0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4 },
        { 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,4,4 },
        { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
        { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,}
    });
```

Now comes the problem. Basically I want to determine which side the player has hit the tile from. However, with the algorithm below the collision only works correctly for the bottom and left side. if the player hits the tile from the top it will state it was hit from the bottom. if the player hits from the right it will specify the left side was hit. if the player hits from the top or right it will show that collision has happened but state it happened on the bottom or left of it.
It will output that the top of the tile has been hit but only when the player is completely in the tile like this[image].

Pretty much the same thing happens when it displays the right side is hit(player moves more to the left slightly than image above)

[image]

**TileMap**

```
        int left = (int)Math.Floor((float)player.playerBounds.Left / TILE_WIDTH);
        int top = (int)Math.Floor((float)player.playerBounds.Top / TILE_HEIGHT);
        int right = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)player.playerBounds.Right / TILE_WIDTH) - 1;
        int bottom = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)player.playerBounds.Bottom / TILE_HEIGHT) - 1;

        Rectangle tileBounds = new Rectangle((int)tilePosX, (int)tilePosY, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        Rectangle playerBounds = player.playerBounds;

        float WidthOfRects = 0.5f * (playerBounds.Width + tileBounds.Width);
        float heightOfRects = 0.5f * (playerBounds.Height + tileBounds.Height);

        int centerX = (playerBounds.Left + playerBounds.Width / 2) - (tileBounds.Left + tileBounds.Width / 2);
        int centerY = (playerBounds.Top + playerBounds.Height / 2) - (tileBounds.Top + tileBounds.Height / 2);

        for (int y = top; y <= bottom; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = left; x <= right; ++x)
            {

                if (mapCell[y, x].TileID == 1)
                {
                    //minkowski sum
                    if (Math.Abs(centerX) <= WidthOfRects && Math.Abs(centerY) <= heightOfRects)
                    {
                        double wy = WidthOfRects * centerY;
                        double hx = heightOfRects * centerX;
                        if (wy > hx)
                        {
                            if (wy > -hx)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("bottom");
                                //newPos.Y = tileCollision.Bottom;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("right");
                                //newPos.X = tileCollision.Right;

                            }
                        }
                        if (wy > -hx)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("left ");
                            //newPos.X = tileCollision.Left - playerBounds.Width;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("top");
                            //newPos.Y = tileCollision.Top - playerBounds.Height;
                        }
                    }
                    // player.Position = newPos;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Map Cell**

```
public class MapCell
{

    public int TileID { get; set; }

    public MapCell(int tileID) 
    {
        TileID = tileID;
    }
```

the player bounds is in the **player class** update method which inherits from the sprite class.

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        playerBounds = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, 50, 50);
    }
```

The position is inheriting from the **sprite class**

```
    protected Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's we have coordinate system with OY axis top-to bottom, player with center position PX, PY, half-width PW, half-height PH, and direction vector DX, DY.

Tile rectangle centered at TX, TY, half-width TW, half-height TH.

Player touches tile when it's central point meets Minkowski's sum rectangle in the first time (t is time parameter)

```
CX = PX + DX * t
CY = PX + DY * t

if DY >= 0 then  //moving down
  t1 = (TY - TH - PH - PY) / DY   //time to meet horizontal edge
else  //moving up
  t1 = (TY + TH + PH - PY) / DY  

if DX >= 0 then //moving right
  t2 = (TX - TW - PW - PX) / DX    //time to meet vertical edge
else  //moving left
  t2 = (TX + TW + PW - PX) / DX  

if t1 <= t2 then
  if DY >= 0 then
    touches top edge first
  else
    touches bottom edge first
else
  if DX >= 0 then
    touches left edge first
  else
    touches right edge first

//you can consider corner touches (t1=t2) separately
```